# Proof assistants and formalised mathematics in the MSC database

Tags: mathematics

I was looking at the [MSC2020 database](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2020.html?t=03Dxx&btn=Current) and I find it hard to identify a field suitable for works about proof assistants and formalised mathematics. 03B70 ("Logic in Computer Science") might be the closest one, but it does not look optimal to me. My questions are

1. Do you think a better subject class exists?
2. If we end up agreeing that there is none (and that one might be needed), is there a way to propose this to the AMS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*TL;DR: Based on the descriptions in the MSC2020 alone, I would use the new section **68Vxx**, specifically the subject classification **68V20** (or maybe **68V15**) if one is formalizing mathematics in a proof assistant.  (However, **68** is CS, so if one is concerned that their work be recognized as pure mathematics, then maybe it shouldn't be the primary classification of the work.)*

---

There appears to be a new section in the [2020 MSC Subject Classification](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/pdfs/classifications2020.pdf):

- **68Vxx Computer science support for mathematical research and practice**

  - **68V05** Computer assisted proofs of proofs-by exhaustion type {For rigorous numerics, see **65Gxx**; for proofs employing automated or interactive theorem provers, see **68V15**}
  - **68V15** Theorem proving (automated and interactive theorem provers, deduction, resolution, etc.) [See also **03B35**]
  - **68V20** Formalization of mathematics in connection with
    theorem provers [See also **03B35**, **68V15**]
  - **68V25** Presentation and content markup for mathematics
  - **68V30** Mathematical knowledge management
  - **68V35** Digital mathematics libraries and repositories
  - **68V99** None of the above, but in this section

Note some of the above subject classifications also cross reference **03B35**, but this classification (from 2010) seems quite vague:

- **03B35** Mechanization of proofs and logical operations [See also **68V15**]

Even, **03B70**, the subject classification you mentioned (which seems to be the de facto standard in the small, biased selection  of arXiv papers I've looked at) also cross references **68-XX**:

- **03B70** Logic in computer science [See also **68-XX**]

Last, the computer science section **68-XX** also mentions the availability of the classifications **-04** for "papers containing software, source code, etc. in a specific mathematical area", e.g.

- **14-04** Software, source code, etc. for problems pertaining to algebraic geometry

---

[There is a small discussion on the Lean Zulip](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113488-general/topic/MSC) about this new section.

---

Here are papers on arXiv using [**68V20**](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=68v20&searchtype=msc_class&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50) and [**68V15**](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=68v15&searchtype=msc_class&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50).

---

I'd also love to get an answer from someone involved in the creation of **68Vxx** or from anyone who feels that **68Vxx** doesn't work for them.

Comment: Lovely, thank you very much. I was not aware of 68V15 or 68V20, that definitely seem to be the best-suited.